# What are the errors in the following Oracle database code?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, the `STAFF` table has four columns:

```
id, first_name, last_name, salary
```

Columns `id` and `salary` are of `NUMBER` datatype, while columns `first_name` and `last_name` are of `VARCHAR2(20)` datatype.

Here is the PL/SQL code that manipulates the STAFF table. Is there any error?

```
v_id NUMBER := 200;
v_fname VARCHAR2(20);
v_lname
v_sal NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT first_name, last_name, salary
INTO v_fname, v_lname
FROM STAFF
WHERE id=v_id;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(v_fname||‘ ‘||v_fname||’ makes ’||v_sal);
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Refer to [Database PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/)

Comment: I have just started learning oracle. Having hard time understanding everything actually.

Comment: Instead of asking the questions about will there be any error, you may create this table and execute your code **to test it by yourself**. Oracle will tell you what is the error

Comment: @astentx Most of the errors are simple syntax errors but there is a non-obvious error in the code of using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT`, which does not flush the current line to the output buffer, and not `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` or `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE`, which both do flush the current line to the output buffer; so even if they did fix all the obvious errors then the code would still never output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

- `DECLARE` at the start.
- `END;` at the end and then a `/` on a newline.
- `'` for string literals and not `‘`
- `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` instead of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT` (which does not flush the line to the buffer).

```sql
DECLARE
    v_id NUMBER := 200;
    v_fname VARCHAR2(20);
    v_lname VARCHAR2(20);
    v_sal NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT first_name, last_name, salary
    INTO v_fname, v_lname, v_sal
    FROM STAFF
    WHERE id=v_id;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_fname||' '||v_fname||' makes '||v_sal);
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9cb1fee43864dcf120c35dd834d2620d)*

Comment: Thanks. If I want to print on the screen a message only in case a salary of the selected record is higher than 5000 pounds what would be the additional PL/SQL Code?

Comment: @MICHAELT. An [`IF` statement.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/if_statement.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't provide a `DECLARE` statement and you left out a type value for `v_lname`. Also you didn't include `v_sal` in the `INTO` clause. Try this:

```
DECLARE
    v_id NUMBER := 200;
    v_fname VARCHAR2(20);
    v_lname VARCHAR2(20);
    v_sal NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT first_name, last_name, salary
    INTO v_fname, v_lname, v_sal
    FROM STAFF
    WHERE id=v_id;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(v_fname||' '||v_fname||' makes '||v_sal);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I guess a few more errors are left. This is what I am getting right now. 

https://prnt.sc/xnBKfOAfNp4R

Comment: As MT0 points out you need to correct your single quotes.